# View of Quiz questions Grouped by their Quiz?

Tags: views, quiz

How do i build the following View configuration:

- Group quiz questions by their assigned Quiz
- Display Quiz title above each grouped list
- Display only One question per group and link question to the Quiz Take Page (All questions in one list. I have "Quiz Pages" module configured.)

Wireframe block:

Quiz1

Question (link to quiz1 questions list page)

Quiz2

Question (link to quiz2 questions list page)

Quiz3

Question (link to quiz3 questions list page)